# Customize position of social icons in upme plugin

Tags: php, customization, css, html, screen-layout

I want to change the position of Social Icons so that they appear in the bottom of profile image. 
[image: How it looks]
[image: How I want it]
I don't know how to change the position of div in the UPME plugin to make this change. I can do it in the inspect element but I can't find the code in plugin.